# problem with my texmaker.exe and miktex packages? doesn't compile

Tags: packages

I started using latex back in 2016. Since then, I had to format my pc 2 times, so i had to redownload miktex and a compiler (I was using texmaker). BUT I can't useW it anymore, like there arent no packages dowloaded or bibliography etc. everything i try to write there comes with an error message. I'M asking: do you recommend to delete all the files and then re-installate it again? or there is certain packages and library i could dowload to integrate what already exist? PLUS: i can switch to texstudio? what do you think? Please, it's important, I have to write my bachelor thesis. thank you to everyone.

edit:
what do you suggest? it's better to delete all files and programs, and reinstallate miktex and one of the compiler (texstudio, texmaker etc).
and if so, there is a "pack of packages" (sorry for the repetition) that i can dowload first and so make the basic functions already working?
because everytime I try to compile one of my past work, it says as error that a lot of packages are missing, when before i already added them. so why? is something not working right since the last time I had to format the pc and re installate everything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You definitely can switch to TeXStudio. IMHO it has a better interface and is more user friendly than TeXMaker. As for your other issues:  what OS are you using? In general deleting a program should be done by the program manager of that OS to prevent incomplete deinstallation.

Comment: Welcome to tex stackexchange! If you need to be able to continue your work in the meantime, you could use an online LaTeX editor like overleaf until the installation on your computer is fixed. Completely removing MiKTeX and the editor, then reinstalling (TeX-distribution before the editor) usually does solve such issues. (There is a very thorough guide for windows on the MiKTeX website which should completely remove it https://miktex.org/faq/uninstall-miktex-win-cli) As @alchemist said, it's important to say which OS you're on if you're going to ask for concrete further steps...

Comment: At the moment I'm using windows 10. i already disinstalled texmaker (opening the control panel > programs > disinstall programs. I was waiting your answers for proceding in deleting also miktex. so, how can i be sure that the deinstallation is complete? (i'm not english, sorry for any mistakes)

Comment: English is actually my third language, @EricaRicciardi . Remove MikTeX using MS Program manager as usual. Then check in the (hidden) folder AppData the two directories Local and Roaming. MikTeX does install some configuration files in those. If present, remove them. You can check the Registry as well on keys that contain MikTeX and remove those. When you’re unsure to change the Registry, just leave that option out. Restart your computer twice (`Voodoo` thing with Windows) and reinstall TeXStudio newest version 4.5 and MikTeX newest version.

Comment: try to compile a minimal hello world document without packages (at best on the command line, but you can also use texworks which is installed together with miktex). Does that compile?

Comment: @alchemist. while removing miktex a message apperead: 
do you want to permanently delete the key of sistyem registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org (Yes/No)? 

so? what do I say? yes or no?

Comment: You can say yes to that. You are going to reinstall MikTeX anyway, so that key will be added again.